# go-testfixtures fixtures.Load() returns Checksum error

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, go

I was following the sample code [here](https://github.com/go-testfixtures/testfixtures/blob/master/README.md) to try set up a test MySQL database with fixtures for unit testing. I have the following code.

```
func prepareTestDatabase() (*sql.DB, error) {
    err := godotenv.Load("../.env")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    conn, err := sql.Open("mysql", os.Getenv("MYSQLURL_TEST"))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    fixtures, err := testfixtures.New(
        testfixtures.Database(conn),
        testfixtures.Dialect("mysql"),
        testfixtures.Files("fixtures/sampledata.yml"),
    )
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    err = fixtures.Load()
    return conn, err
}
```

But `fixtures.Load()` failed and returned error:

```
sql: Scan error on column index 1, name "Checksum": converting NULL to int64 is unsupported
```

The YAML file I used was like the following:

```
- id: 1
  varchar_col: somevarchar
  decimal_col: 9999.99
  int_col: 123456789
  created_at: 2020-05-17 00:01:59

- id: 2
  varchar_col: somevarchar
  decimal_col: 9999.99
  int_col: 987654321
  created_at: 2020-05-17 00:01:59
```

So probably the sample data was not inserted into the database? I am sure database connection is fine and I can insert and read data from the test database.

Answer (score 0):

Your file `sampledata.yml` should have the same name as table. For example: for `user` table it should be `user.yml` file